# SIGABRT Vector Allocation Problem on C++ 11

Tags: c++, stdvector, allocation

I implemented a Priority Queue and its sorted himself with using vector
`

```
void sortQueue() {
    std::vector<double> orders;
    while (front != -1) {
        orders.push_back(this->deQueue());
    }
    sort(orders.begin(), orders.end(), [](double o1, double o2) { return o1 < o2; });
    for (int i = 0; i < orders.size(); ++i) {
        this->Queue::enQueue(orders.back());
    }
}
```

but after all lines of the function are executed gives that error

free(): invalid pointer Signal: SIGABRT (Aborted) on new_allocator.h

explanation on debugger is

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted. 0x00007ffff788957c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted. The program no longer exists.

Comment: The problem with memory corruption bugs is that they often manifest far away from the place that caused them.

Comment: Add `-g -fsanitize=address` to your compiler flags and rerun the program. Look at the reported lines. If that does not help, please provide us a compilable code snippet, that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The code is not a [mcve].  It is obviously code taken from within a class, and we have no idea if the class instance is valid, when, where, or how any of those fields are populated, etc.  Also, there is no issue with `vector` in that little bit of code you posted -- a `push_back` of a `double` and `std::sort` will not cause issues, *unless* what I mentioned is occurring (invalid object, memory mismanagement, etc. in other parts of the code).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes it's my fault, my gdb gives sigabrt when the allocation of vector and so I thought the problem was about vector